# Why is one dimensional array of ref to other one-dimensional array called multi dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I know array reference, but in Perl multidimensional array is a one dimensional array of reference to other one-dimensional array can anyone explain this with an example?

Comment: Do you have a specific code example to describe what you mean? I'm having an incredibly hard time parsing your question.

Comment: @Matt Jacob : below coding is my answer , i am asking about any example code with explanation for 2 dimensional array

Answer (score 2):

```
my @a = ( "a", "b", "c" );
my @x;
$x[4] = \@a;
say $x[4]->[2];  # c
```

The dereference (`->`) is implied "between indexes" if omitted.

```
my @a = ( "a", "b", "c" );
my @x;
$x[4] = \@a;
say $x[4][2];  # c
```

As you can see, this can be used to create multi-dimensional arrays.

---

An anonymous array is commonly used. `[ ... ]` constructs an array and returns a reference to it.

```
my @x;
$x[4] = [ "a", "b", "c" ];
say $x[4][2];  # c
```

Also common is to let Perl create the array and the reference for you automatically through a feature called "autovivification".

```
my @x;
$x[4][2] = "c";
say $x[4][2];  # c
```

That's because

```
$x[4][2] = "c";
```

is short for

```
$x[4]->[2] = "c";
```

and

```
SCALAR->[EXPR1] = EXPR2;
```

is effectively

```
( SCALAR //= [ ] )->[EXPR1] = EXPR2;
```

so

```
$x[4]->[2] = "c";
```

is effectively

```
( $x[4] //= [ ] )->[2] = "c";
```

Comment: @kegami :( $x[4] //= [ ] )->[2] = "c"; I couldn't understand this line can u explain this line?

Comment: `SCALAR //= EXPR` checks if `SCALAR` is defined. If not, it evaluates `EXPR` and assigns the result to `SCALAR`.

Comment: $x[4] = \@a; if reference would not be use what will be happen? like this $x[4] = @a;

Comment: Same as `$x[4] = 3;`, since `@a` in scalar context evaluates to the number of elements in `@a`.

Answer (score 0):

There are different uses of "dimension" at play here, and I recently was working in a language that used the other one. That messed me up for a moment while I had to switch thinking.

In some domains, the "dimension" is the number of elements. In others, it's the number of things you have to specify to get to an element. Some uses use the term incorrectly (or sloppily). This is incredibly reductive, but I think that's the spirit. This means, though, that you can't transfer what you know about "dimension" from one use to another use. You have to know what the particular tool thinks it means.

### Simple math

Forget about programming for a moment and think about simple math, which I'll also crudely simplify.

A point (vector, whatever) with just an x and a y coordinate, say (1,2), is two dimensional because there are two things you need to specify it completely. A point with (x,y,z) is three dimensional, and so on, up to whatever multiple you like. This sort of use is a bit sloppy because a point with three coordinates is still a point (a one dimensional thing) even if it lives is a three dimensional space. But, through a bit of synedoche that's how people talk.

Then consider matrices. These have rows and columns. The rows have a certain number of thingys and the columns have a certain number of thingys. The dimension of the matrix is a combination of the number of rows and columns (there's a bit more to it, but ignore that). Someone might say they have a "three by three matrix".

Perl's use of "multi" tends more to the matrix idea.

### Matrices in Perl

Perl basically has three major built-in data types (there are a few others that aren't important here). You have scalars, which are single things, lists, which are zero of more scalars, and hashes. Perl doesn't get much more complicated than that. Somehow, we have to use that simple foundation to make fancier things:

Since Perl does not have a matrix type, we fake it with anonymous arrays (see the [perl data structures cookbook](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc) and [Perl list of lists](https://perldoc.perl.org/perllol)). A reference is single thingy, so a scalar.

```
my $ref = [     # top level
  [ 0, 1, 2 ],  # first row
  [ 3, 4, 5 ],  # second row
  [ 6, 7, 8 ],  # third row
];
```

Inside that top level array reference, there are three elements that are each anonymous arrays themselves. Think of those as rows. The particular position in each row is like a column. To get to any particular spot, we specify the (zero-based) row and column number:

```
$ref->[2][2];
```

That use of multiple subscripts to address any particular element gives us the "multi" in Perl. That's just how Perl uses the term, right or wrong and despite how it's used any other place.

So, finally to your question about an array ref holding a single array ref of one item:

```
my $ref = [     # top level
  [ 'Camel' ],  # first row
];
```

Having one row and one column is as correct as any other number or rows and columns. To get to that element, we still need to specify the row and column. They both happen to be `0`.

```
$ref->[0][0];
```

And, finally, we have the trivial case of no rows or columns:

```
my $ref = [];
```

Remember though, that Perl never fixes the sizes here. It's happy to give you undef for any element you ask for:

```
my $value = $ref->[999][999];
```

And if you assign to any index higher than what it already has, it creates all the elements it needs to it can have that index. This one assignment gets you a 1000 by 1000 "matrix":

```
$ref->[999][999] = 'Hello';
```

### Just for fun

The references are a Perl 5 feature, but multi-dimensional things go back to at least Perl 3. We used to fake multi-dimensional thingys with goofy hash keys. We'd separate the indices with `,` (or whatever the value of `$;` was:

```
$some_hash{1,3,7} = 'foo';
```

This was the same as:

```
$key = join $;, 1, 3, 7;
$some_hash{$key}
```

As long as your sub-keys didn't have the value of `$;` in them, this worked out.

This still exists in Perl, but starting with v5.36 (the latest as I write this), it's turned off:

```
use v5.36;  # no multidimensional
```

Or you can turn it off:

```
no multidimensional;
```

If you really need it and still want to require a minimum of v5.36, you can re-enable it:

```
use v5.36;
use multidimensional;
```

Or, use `require` which doesn't do the `feature` stuff (but then you have to figure out what else you aren't getting but may want):

```
require v5.36;
```